# Is there a way to add a cache between Apollo Gateway and federated services?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, apollo-federation

I am using Apollo Federation and I have a question regarding caching.

Right now I have a query like this where'd I'd like to get the author of a post:

```
query GetPost {
  post(id: "123") {
    id
    author {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Post is one service and Author is another. "id" is included on the post model because that's expected when using the client-side apollo libraries.

When that query runs, two requests are made internally: One to each service.

Now, the generated request (by the gateway) to the post service is really simple and looks like this:

```
query {
  post(id: "123") {
    id
  }
}
```

I get thousands of these every minute and would like to cache them. Obviously, getting the ID of a post by ID will never change, so every request like this is a waste.

Is there a way to cache this request on the gateway side? So that it doesn't make the request to the post service.

Comment: I guess ... no `authorId` in `Post` type ... and that's why there is no simple possibility to ask for post author data? - separate request in some `<Author/>` component (cached at client, queried only when required) - simply `authorById` ... on the other way why all data not queried on `Post` level and author data not passed as prop? why it requires a separate query? ... bad client design? not optimized, no costs/limits/no need?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/api/apollo-gateway/#configuring-the-implementing-service-fetcher), you can customize the fetcher that is used to retreive the data from your implementing services by extending the RemoteGraphQLDataSource class. The custom fetcher can be any function which implements the fetch specification, in this example I'm using [node-fetch-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch-cache) to persist the queries to disk on the gateway.

```js
const { ApolloGateway, RemoteGraphQLDataSource } = require("@apollo/gateway");

class CachingDataSource extends RemoteGraphQLDataSource {
    fetcher = require('node-fetch-cache')('./locaCache');
}

const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
    serviceList: [
        { name: "post", url: "http://posts.service" },
        { name: "author", url: "http://author.service" },
    ],
    buildService({ name, url }) {
        if (url === "http://posts.service") {
            return new CachingDataSource({ url, name });
        } else {
            return new RemoteGraphQLDataSource({
                url,
                name
            });
        }
    },
});
```